# Rewrite condition if not match url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

In my Zend Framework 2 project i'am redirecting https to http but I would like this redirection not to be effective on certain URLs, I tried this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect no-www to www only main domain, not with subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect https to http all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

# active la génération des en-têtes Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

If i go to https admin url, i'am redirected to mydomaine.net/index.php but i dont know why ?

Comment: If SSL will work in only certain folders then I would stop redirecting entire site to https and put .htaccess in the necessary folders with the SSL redirect only. Redirect directive would be:  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/necessary_folder/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Can you change "!^/admin.*" to "!^/?admin.*", maybe this can help.